# What is the correct way to convert a static gutenberg block created using @wordpress/create-block into a dynamic block registering it using PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I've been searching long and hard to find the answer to this but every tutorial or advice I follow so far has let me down.

I'm trying to convert a static Gutenberg block I created for WordPress into a dynamic block. To do this the block must be registerd in PHP using register_block_type() instead of using block.json.

According to every tutorial I have read all I should need to do is change the register_block_type function inside the plugins main php file.

In the PHP file for the static version which works I did have...

```
function wholesomecode_wholesome_plugin_block_init() {
    register_block_type( __DIR__ );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wholesomecode_wholesome_plugin_block_init' );
```

I then updated the register_block_type function to this...

```
function wholesomecode_wholesome_plugin_block_init() {
    if ( ! function_exists( 'register_block_type' ) ) {
        // Block editor is not available.
        return;
    }
    register_block_type( 'wholesomecode/wholesome-plugin', [
          'attributes'      => [
            'blockText' => [
              'default' => 'Wholesome Plugin - hello from the editor!',
              'type'    => 'string',
            ],
          ],
          'editor_script'   => 'wholesomecode-wholesome-plugin-block-editor',
          'editor_style'    => 'wholesomecode-wholesome-plugin-block-editor',
          'render_callback' => function( $attributes, $content ) {
            $block_text = esc_html( $attributes['blockText'] );
            return "<p class='wp-block-wholesomecode-wholesome-plugin'>$block_text</p>";
          },
          'style'           => 'wholesomecode-wholesome-plugin-block',
        ]
      );
}
add_action( 'init', 'wholesomecode_wholesome_plugin_block_init' );
```

In index.js in the src directory I have also updated the save method so it returns null.

Now when I build and run the block it doesn't show up in the block editor in WordPress.

If anyone you could help me you'd definitely be saving me a few lost hairs and sleepsless nights becuase I've trying at this for days now.

Answer (score 0):

A block created with `@wordpress/create-block` can be converted to a dynamic block with only a few minor changes to the generated files. I would suggest recreating your block to get back to the original files/project structure before making these changes:

1. Create a render callback function, eg `render_create_block_wholesome_plugin()` to handle the server side rendering of your block. This could be in either in the main plugin file or a separate php file included in the main plugin.

```php
    <?php
    // Render callback function
    function render_create_block_wholesome_plugin($attributes, $content)
    {
        $block_text = esc_html($attributes['blockText']);
        return sprintf('<p class="wp-block-create-block-wholesome-plugin">%1$s</p>', $block_text);
    }
```

2. In the main plugin file,  add `render_callback` with the name of your function to  `register_block_type()` to render the block.

**wholesome-plugin.php**

```php
 function create_block_wholesome_plugin_block_init() {
     // Using the built version of block.json to define block + PHP render callback
     register_block_type(__DIR__ . '/build', array(
         'render_callback' => 'render_create_block_wholesome_plugin'
     ));
 }
 add_action( 'init', 'create_block_wholesome_plugin_block_init' );
```

3. All other block properties should remain in *block.json*. From [WordPress 5.8](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/block-api/block-metadata/) using `block.json` for defining blocks is the recommended approach.

**block.json**

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schemas.wp.org/trunk/block.json",
    "apiVersion": 2,
    "name": "create-block/wholesome-plugin",
    "attributes": {
        "blockText": {
            "default": "Wholesome Plugin - hello from the editor!",
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    ...
    "textdomain": "wholesome-plugin",
    "editorScript": "file:./index.js",
    "editorStyle": "file:./index.css",
    "style": "file:./style-index.css"
}
```

4. As the block is now rendered by PHP, `save.js` can be safely deleted from your project. Also remember to remove `import save from './save';` from  *index.js* and update `registerBlockType()`, eg:

**index.js**

```jsx
import { registerBlockType } from '@wordpress/blocks';
import './style.scss';

/**
 * Internal dependencies
 */
import Edit from './edit';

registerBlockType( 'create-block/wholesome-plugin', {
    /**
     * @see ./edit.js
     */
    edit: Edit,
    // Remove save - default is null, no need to add return null
} );
```

After making the changes above, build/run your project and now you should have a basic dynamic block setup ready for further development..

Comment: I can't get existing static blocks already in Posts to validate and be rendered server-side. Attributes for newly inserted blocks don't get saved to the database (get blank fields on editor reload), which was from having the block attributes include "source" and "selector" data because those only work for the save function in static blocks. Removing all of those from my block's block.json file fixed that issue, but then it led to existing instances of the original static block to no longer work, which I believe is because there's a conflict now with the Deprecation functionality. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Kory Sounds deprecation/updating issues with your existing blocks markup stored in post content; the attributes named differently or not referenced properly. If you are still having this issue, please post as new question with your PHP function.

Comment: @s-walsh I created a new question and posted all of my files. It might be a bit unwieldy for someone to review, but if you're inspired, here is the link to the StackOverflow question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74988033/how-can-i-convert-a-static-gutenberg-block-into-a-dynamic-block-registering-it-u